# How many counts are in each types in each year? With either group_by() or Split()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame `df` as follows:

```
df
    Code Time         Country Type
1   n001 2000          France    1
2   n002 2001           Japan    5
3   n003 2003             USA    2
4   n004 2004             USA    2
5   n005 2004          Canada    1
6   n006 2005         Britain    2
7   n007 2005             USA    1
8   n008 2005             USA    2
9   n010 2005             USA    1
10  n011 2005          Canada    1
11  n012 2005             USA    2
12  n013 2005             USA    5
13  n014 2005          Canada    1
14  n015 2006             USA    2
15  n017 2006          Canada    1
16  n018 2006         Britain    1
17  n019 2006          Canada    1
18  n020 2006             USA    1
...
```

where `Type` is the type of news, and `Time` is the year when the news was published.
My aim is to count the number of each type of news each year.

I was thinking about a result like this:

```
...
$2005
Type: 1   Count: 4
Type: 2   Count: 3
Type: 5   Count: 1

$2006
Type: 1   Count: 4
...
```

I used the following code:

```
gp = group_by(df, Time)
summarise(gp, table(Time)
```

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: unique() applies only to vectors.

Then I tried `split( )`, thinking it may be able to separate the dataframe by year so I could count the number of each type by year

```
split(df, 'Time')

$Time
    Code Time         Country Type
1   n001 2000          France    1
2   n002 2001           Japan    5
3   n003 2003             USA    2
4   n004 2004             USA    2
...
```

Everything is almost the same, apart from the "$Time" sign.

I was wondering what I did wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried `library(dplyr); df %>% 
  group_by(Time, Type) %>% 
  tally()` or `library(dplyr); df %>% 
  group_by(Time, Type) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n())` or `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, .N, by = .(Time,  Type)]`?

Answer (score 1):

We can `split` `Type` Column by `Time` and calculate it's frequency by `table`.

```
lapply(split(df$Type, df$Time), table)


#$`2000`
#1 
#1 

#$`2001`
#5 
#1 

#$`2003`
#2 
#1 

#$`2004`
#1 2 
#1 1 

#$`2005`
#1 2 5 
#4 3 1 

#$`2006`
#1 2 
#4 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df %>%
   group_by(Time, Type) %>%
   count() %>%
   spread(Type, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this. split on Time, then group by Type and tally the result

```
df %>% 
  split(.$Time) %>% 
  map(~ group_by(., Type) %>% tally())

......
$`2004`
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   Type     n
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     1

$`2005`
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   Type     n
  <int> <int>
1     1     4
2     2     3
3     5     1

$`2006`
# A tibble: 2 x 2
......
```

Or use summarise instead of tally if you want a column called count instead of n

```
df1 %>% 
  split(.$Time) %>% 
  map(~ group_by(., Type) %>% summarise(count = n()))
```